# How do I Load a .webp file into a TypeScript file for later use in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `Weapon` class that has at least one icon.

```
export default abstract class Weapon {
  icons: string[]; // May be the wrong type to use here

  constructor(iconOrIcons: string | string[]) {
    this.icons = typeof iconOrIcons === 'string' ? [iconOrIcons] : iconOrIcons;
  }
}
```

Each icon is `.webp` and I am importing them like so:

```
import icon from '../../../assets/weapons/swords/dagger.webp';
import Sword from './Sword';

export default new Sword(icon);
```

However, these files just being in my project (not even trying to render the images) Webpack throws with:

```
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '♦' (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Okay so Webpack makes it clear that I need a loader. But it's not clear to me how to add a loader to `angular.json`.

It may also be the case that I don't actually need/want to import the `.webp` file itself and I can just use the URLs that point to those resources. In that case, I would ideally like to have some better way to declare those URLs than just having arbitrary string literals on my `Weapon` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the 2nd part of your question.  I think the problem is with the import and you probably just do not need that.

it's probably true you just need the image location so you can use it in an .html.  so instead of importing (which looks for typescript classes), you could just use a string variable?

something like:

```
const icon: string = '../../../assets/weapons/swords/dagger.webp';
```

all you have to do is pass that value to something like an img tag in an .html file and it will render the image.. you shouldn't need a loader, etc.

```
<img src="{{ icon }}" />
```

Thanks!

PS. as far as the string literals, you'll probably be stuck with something like that but you could make it more dynamic like this:

```
const weaponIconsDirectory: string = '../../../assets/weapons/';
const icon: string = weaponIconsDirectory + weaponName + .'webp';
```

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I'm probably just overcomplicating this. It's unfortunate there isn't a better solution than just having magic strings within the app that you won't know work (or fail) until runtime.

Comment: i won't be mad if you mark it as the accepted answer :)  also just a PS.  if you ever get to the point were you are creating your own angular packages.  you will be able to leverage your own package.json and public apis to expose your own libraries/classes, and that is what enables things to be "imported" from other libraries.  but no need to import individual images